# Using JSON Files for localization in GetX

Tags: localization, flutter-getx

I am trying to read translation files eg. `en.json` to use with GetX localization. I tried the following code but no success. Is there any better way of doing it? Somebody suggested using [auto_localize](https://github.com/marcinsiedlik/auto_localized) with GetX, but I'll really appreciate if I can proceed without an extra package

```
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        "ar": readJson("ar"),
        "en": readJson("en"),
}
```

I tried loading the localization information using the following function

```
 // Fetch content from the json file
  Map<String, String> readJson(String languageCode) {
    Map data = {};
    rootBundle
        .loadString('assets/translations/$languageCode.json')
        .then((response) {
      data = json.decode(response);
    });
    return data.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
    });
  }
```

DebugPrint() gets shows that the files were successfully loaded. However, trying to display the loaded Maps doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **readJson** should be Future and because of that the empty Map returned at the end.

#### The way i did

- create languages.json file and put all texts to it.

```
[
  {
    "name": "English",
    "code": "en_US",
    "texts": {
      "hello": "Hello World"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Arabic",
    "code": "ar_AE",
    "texts": {
      "hello": "مرحبا بالعالم"
    }
  }
]
```

- implement localization class like this

```
class LocalizationService extends Translations {

  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {};

  static Future<void> initLanguages() async {
    final _keys = await readJson();
    Get.clearTranslations();
    Get.addTranslations(_keys);
  }

  static Future<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> readJson() async {
    final res = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/languages.json');
    List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(res);
    final listData = data.map((j) => I18nModel.fromJson(j)).toList();
    final keys = Map<String, Map<String, String>>();
    listData.forEach((value) {
      final String translationKey = value.code!;
      keys.addAll({translationKey: value.texts!});
    });
    return keys;
  }
}
```

> As you see after getting the Map data, i used **Get.addTranslations();** to set language keys.
> this is a GetX function to add languages on air!

- create model class to parse json data

```
class I18nModel {
  String? name;
  String? code;
  Map<String, String>? texts;

  I18nModel(
      {this.name, this.code, this.texts});

  I18nModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    code = json['code'];
    if (json['texts'] != null) {
      texts = Map<String, String>.from(json['texts']);
    }
  }
}
```

- And finally call **await LocalizationService.initLanguages();** before going to your first Route.